Supabase,Postgresql. How to filter array of objects stored as JSON in a column
I have a column in a view called all_devices of type json. Each row stores arrays of objects that have this structure:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "device_type": 3,
    "device_name": "AC",
    "is_on": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "device_type": 0,
    "device_name": "Light Bulb",
    "is_on": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "device_type": 2,
    "device_name": "TV",
    "is_on": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "device_type": 1,
    "device_name": "Carbon Dioxide Alarm",
    "is_on": false
  }
]

I use js supabase client and what I want to achieve is to filter array of objects to get devices with device_type that equal 0. I want to get this done for each row so I will get only devices with a certain type for each room.
I tried with something like this:
const { data } = await supabase.from(xyz).select(`id,label,all_devices`).eq('all_devices ->> device_type', 0);
   ```
   but it just returns me an empty array.


